# Intel NUC 10 bios image with settings

Tags: bios, automation, intel-nuc

In earlier Intel NUC versions, it was possible to boot into the UEFI console and run the following command:

```
ITK6.efi -b -x target.bio -ib source.bio -ic -is
```

which would, as an input, receive a bios image (downloaded from Intel) and would create a new custom bios image that contains all bios settings that have been applied at the device at hand.

Then, when setting up new NUCs, you could use this custom bios image to auto-update everything to this bios version and to all the settings.

With the newer versions of the NUCs, this procedure does not seem to be supported anymore. How should one now go about automating the process of updating the bios settings?

Comment: Are you fully following [this procedure](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000023875/intel-nuc.html)?

Comment: Oh, sorry for the confusion, I didn't mean the splash screen image but rather the image of bios software.

Comment: The splash screen part is an example, you should look at the whole article.

Comment: I see - the issue is though that ITK6 does not support Intel NUC 10 and VCUST does not seem to support import/export of bios settings.